# HeidiSQL, how to export user definition

Tags: mariadb, export, mariadb-10.5, heidisql

I am using MariaDB version 10.5.9.0 on Windows version 10.0.19041.928 with HeidiSQL version 11.0.0.5919

I have exported the database structure which includes the tables, stored procedures and data.  I also want to export the user I created to access the database.

In HeidiSQL I select the **Tools** top line menu option, then **Export database as SQL**, I check the database I want to export in this case called **training**, in the **SQL export** tab I check the **Drop** checkboxes for **Database(s)** and **Table(s)**, the **Data:** drop down is set to **Insert**, **Output:** is **Single.sql file**, **Filename:** is supplied the location and name to export to.

From the **mysql** schema I check the **user** table, then I click the **Export** button.

The SQL file created contains the structure of the user table but no inserts present where as the training database contains all the inserts and the stored procedures.  Is there a reason why the user inserts are missing?

I want to use the SQL file as a complete set-up.

Comment: i think it is a bug, Have you tried it with another tool

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0.24 build 681332, seems is now incompatible with this version of MariaDB. "Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (10.5.9)."  I will just have to put it together myself.

Comment: workbench 8.0.x has in the last versions only concentrated on mysql 8.x, and lost some compability with older Versions